# Node.JS Express routing not working as it should work

Tags: express, npm, nodejs-server

File structure:

[image: file structure]

In `/server/routes/index.js`

```js
const Router = require('express');
const router = Router();

const deviceRouter = require('./deviceRouter');
const brandRouter = require('./brandRouter');
const typeRouter = require('./typeRouter');
const userRouter = require('./userRouter');

router.use('/user', userRouter);
router.use('/type', typeRouter);
router.use('/brand', brandRouter);
router.use = router.use('/device', deviceRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

In `server/index.js`

```js
const router = require('routes/index')
```

I got an error at this part. Basically, error comes from `/server/routes/index.js` as

```js
const Router = require('express');
const router = Router(); not working.
```

Here is how it looks in WebStorm:

[image: here is how it looks in WebStorm]

and here is how it **should** look in WebStorm:

[image: and here is how it should look in WebStorm]

Comment: Hey, I'm kinda newbie into this, and maybe I have to install something before to get this work? Anyway, please, help

Answer (score 1):

Don’t do that :

```
const Router = require('express');
const router = Router();
```

Try this instead :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
```

Test with this exemple and if it works then try to adapt it in your project :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/index", (req, res)=> {
 res.json({
   message: "success"
 })
});
```

In your index file try this :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use("/user", userRouter);
```

Comment: already did, still not working. I feel useless, anyway, I'll try to do the whole project again.

Comment: Instead of router.use() try with app.use()

Comment: Why should the OP use your other method? Important information such as this makes an already good answer, better therefore attracting more upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in `/server/routes/index.js` to the following and paste it into `server/index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const deviceRouter = require('./routes/deviceRouter');
const brandRouter = require('./routes/brandRouter');
const typeRouter = require('./routes/typeRouter');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRouter');

app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/type', typeRouter);
app.use('/brand', brandRouter);
app.use('/device', deviceRouter);
```

Delete this file: `/server/routes/index.js`. No need to make this file `server/router/index.js` for routes, instead call all your routes the way I did. And if you still want to keep all routes in `server/routes/index.js` file then do in the following way:

Add in `server/index.js`:

```
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');

app.use(indexRoutes);
```

Change `server/routes/index.js` file to:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const deviceRouter = require('./deviceRouter');
const brandRouter = require('./brandRouter');
const typeRouter = require('./typeRouter');
const userRouter = require('./userRouter');

app.use('/user', userRouter);
app.use('/type', typeRouter);
app.use('/brand', brandRouter);
app.use('/device', deviceRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

And that's all, you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got an answer! The problem was **not properly implementing** /server/routes/index.js **into** /server/index.js. Make sure you did it right.

In my case:

**server/routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express();

const deviceRouter = require('./deviceRouter');
const brandRouter = require('./brandRouter');
const typeRouter = require('./typeRouter');
const userRouter = require('./userRouter');

router.use('/user', userRouter);
router.use('/type', typeRouter);
router.use('/brand', brandRouter);
router.use('/device', deviceRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

**server/index.js**

```
const indexRoutes = require('./routes/index')
app.use(indexRoutes)
```

Also, stupid deviceRouter mistake

[image: stupid deviceRouter mistake]